# Composer VCS Different Directory Name

Tags: php, git, composer-php, packagist

When using Composer to load a package from a VCS repository, is there a way to specify which folder to install the contents in to (similar to `git clone <directory>`)?

For example the repo is:

```
https://github.com/organization/plugin_name.git
```

And thus composer file reads:

```
"repositories": [
    {
    "type": "vcs",
          "url": "https://github.com/organization/plugin_name.git"
}]

"require": {
"organization/plugin_name": "dev-master",
}
```

Whereas the directory I want the contents to be is not "plugin_name" but something like "organization_plugin-title".

I have several repos (custom WP plugins) that have one name, but a different folder name within my WordPress MU setup, and I'd really like to not have to enable each one manually within the admin after updating my composer file.

Answer (score 3):

Naturally answered my own question once I posted...

In the repo's composer.json file, the "name" field should be what you want the directory to be called when installed. I erroneously thought it had to be the name of the repo.

Be sure to then edit the local install's composer.json file so under the "required" section it is the same name as seen in the repo's composer.json file